# Wie nennt man eine Kinderfrisur mit zwei nicht geflochtenen seitlichen "Pferdeschwänzchen"?

Tags: single-word-request

In einer Talkrunde im Fernsehen nannte ein Gast ihre Kinderfrisur *"Rattenschwänzchen"*. Ich erinnere mich, dass in meiner Kindheit eine Mädchenfrisur auch so genannt wurde. Den anderen Gästen war dieser Begriff aber gänzlich unbekannt. Nach der Beschreibung war diese Frisur gemeint:

[image]
<sup>Wikimedia</sup>

In der englischsprachigen Wikipedia "List of Hairstyles" wird sie *"Pigtail"* genannt. Über eine deutsche Bezeichnung habe ich aber nichts finden können. Ein "[Rattenschwanz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rattenschwanz)" ist eine völlig andere Frisur.

Weiß jemand wie man die oben gezeigte Frisur nennt? Gibt es vielleicht regionale Unterschiede?

Comment: Das Wort Pigtails kommt aus dem Englischen und bedeutet wörtlich übersetzt **„Schweineschwänzchen“**. Als Pigtails bezeichnet man zwei Zöpfe, die sich rechts und links am Kopf befinden. Auch mehr als zwei Zöpfe werden manchmal Pigtails genannt.

Comment: Achja, den Satz habe ich von hier kopiert: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zopf

Comment: @Em1: Ich habe aber noch nie etwas von *"Schweineschwänzchen"* gehört, Du?

Comment: Meine Freundin (Saarländerin) bezeichnet die Frisur als _Bietzen_. Ich habe trotz längerem googeln den Begriff nicht gefunden - kann also weder die richtige Schreibung noch die Korrektheit garantieren. Deshalb auch nur als Kommentar und nicht als Antwort.

Comment: Bei Leo wurde man auch nicht wirklich fündig: http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=19180&idForum=4&lp=esde&lang=de

Comment: Würde die wörtliche Übersetzung nicht eher **„Schweineschwänze“** lauten?

Comment: Google findet jedenfalls auch einige Rattenschwänzchen.

Comment: In my youth pigtails were always plaited. The style in the picture was called "bunches".

Comment: @Knut: Ob verwandt kann ich nicht sagen, aber ich finde `NRhWB Bitzel Ahrw-Remag. Neuw-Erpel m.: Ungeduld.Bitzel-bart Saarbr-Sulzb m.: kleiner Kinnbart. Bitzel-schnüsse -nis Saarbr-Neud f.: vorlautes Mädchen.` im [http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=RhWB&lemid=RB04098 ](Wörterbuchnetz)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seit der Nachkriegs-Schulzeit wurde diese Frisur im Norddeutschen schon immer schlicht und einfach "Rattenschwänze" genannt. Mit der Übersetzung aus dem Englischen hat das überhaupt nichts zu tun, und ein Pferdeschwanz ist sozusagen ein einzelner Rattenschwanz auf dem Hinterkopf. Auch mit Zöpfen hat das gar nichts zu tun, denn hierzu muß man die Haare FLECHTEN!

Comment: Das deckt sich mit meinen Erfahrungen. Hast du irgendwo einen Beleg darüber gefunden?

Comment: die heißen auch in ganz Mitteldeutschland so

Comment: Die Frage ist ja schon etwas älter und mittlerweile hat die "Zwei hinter den Ohren getragene offene Zöpfe"-Version auch den Weg in den in der Frage erwähnten Wikipedia-Artikel gefunden.

Comment: "Auch mit Zöpfen hat das gar nichts zu tun, denn hierzu muß man die Haare FLECHTEN!" - ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch alles, was Haare im Bündel vom Kopf abstehen oder herunterhängen lässt, als "Zopf" aufgefasst wird.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das geht gar nicht. Was nicht geflochten ist, ist auf keinen Fall ein Zopf. Das sträuben sich mir die Nackenhaare ;) Wikipedia liegt falsch.

Answer (score 4):

Es scheint dafür tatsächlich kein deutsches, allgemein verständliches Wort zu geben. Selbst die deutsche Wikipedia-Seite nennt dies einfach ["Pigtails"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zopf#Pigtails) - also:

- den englischen Begriff "Pigtails" benutzen
- auf die wörtliche Übersetzung "Schweineschwänzchen" ausweichen, die wahrscheinlich noch weniger verstanden wird
- einfach "Zöpfe" sagen - wobei hier die genaue Anzahl (2) und die Anordnung (seitlich links und rechts) nicht eindeutig ist

Comment: oder einfach *zwei kurze Zöpfe* sagen; so zumindest die Bildbeschreibung auf Wikipedia zum - in der Frage geposteten - Foto.

Comment: *"Schweineschwänzchen"* gibt es meines Wissens nur beim Metzger/Fleischer.

Comment: @Takkat [Sheilas kecke Aufmachung – Schottenröcke und die berühmte “Schweineschwänzchen”-Frisur – wird von zahlreichen französischen Teenagern kopiert](http://www.famous-people.de/sheila.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Das ist vermutlich nicht der korrekte Friseur-Begriff, aber ich würde diese Zöpfe "Pippi-Langstrumpf-Zöpfe" nennen. In dem Fall weiß vermutlich jeder was gemeint ist.

Comment: Danke fuer die Umlaute and apologies for my lazyness ;)

Comment: Nein, bei Pippi Langstrumpf würde ich an _geflochtene_ Zöpfe denken.

Comment: Pipi Langstrumpf hingegen besitzt tatsächlich *Zöpfe*, denn sie sind *geflochten*. Wären sie das nicht, dann wären es *Rattenschwänze*, die regional auch anders genannt werden.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Google Images gibt dir gewissermaßen Recht, da Pippis Zöpfe tatsächlich mit einer oder zwei "Flechtwindungen" beginnen. Vor dem Nachsehen hatte sich meine Erinnerung aber in der Tat auf die weit offenen Pferdeschwanz-artigen Zopfenden beschränkt.

Answer (score 2):

Im Saarland  wird die Frisur als `Bietzen` (moselfränkischer Teil) oder  `Bienzchen` bzw. `Bienzja` (rheinfränkisches Saarland) bezeichnet.

Neben dem Verweis in [meinem Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/wie-nennt-man-eine-kinderfrisur-mit-zwei-nicht-geflochtenen-seitlichen-pferdesc#comment8422_3774) habe ich zwei weitere *Belege* erhalten, einer [mit Bildreferenz](http://jonahs-welt.blogspot.de/2009/09/neue-frisur.html). Auf Nachfrage zu den `Bietzen` erhielt ich folgende Antwort:

> Auf saarländisch sind Bietzen 2 "Zöpfe".
> Ob geflochten oder wie bei ihrem Beispiel einfach mit 2 Gummis gehalten spielt dabei keine Rolle.

> Bietzen ist wohl eine rein saarländische Worterfindung, wobei jeder Saarländer wohl weiß, was damit gemeint ist.

Comment: Zwar nicht "seriös", deine weiter Referenz, aber lustig. Danke für die Antwort :)

Comment: Zumindest waren es jetzt zwei unabhängige Aussagen. Vorher hätte es auch ein _Familienwort_ sein können.

Comment: Und noch ein _Nachweis_ - ich habe die Antwort angepasst.

Comment: "wobei jeder Saarländer wohl weiß"... also, mir war der Begriff neu...

Answer (score 2):

Auch hier in den Niederlanden sagt man *"Pippi Langkous"*-Haare; die sind auch auf beiden Seiten aber ganz rot (und nicht, wie Hendrik Vogt meinte, geflochten!).

- [wiki](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aHair_fashion?uselang=nl#mw-subcategories)
  oder
- [wiki nur damenfrisur](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aFemale_hair_fashion)

.